# I can't login using the previously defined users after I have published my asp.net mvc app to IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-express

I am developing an asp.net mvc web application using MS visual developer express 2010. When I publish the web application to IIS 7 express on localhost, I am facing the following problems:

1. I can't login using the previous application users.
2. If I register a new user from the application and want to assign a new role for the new user, then this user will not appear in the list of system users in the "Web Site Administration Tool" under the "security" section, and the "Web Site Administration Tool"  will only display the old users that I can't login using their credentials.

So what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [link](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/users-and-roles-on-the-production-website-vb)

Especially these bits:

Unfortunately, the WSAT is only accessible locally. You cannot visit the WSAT on your remote production website; if you visit www.yoursite.com/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx you get a 404 Not Found response.

...

In a nutshell, the WSAT must be accessed locally through the development environment, and it works with the user and role information in the database specified in the databaseConnectionStrings.config file. Consequently, if we change the connection string information in the databaseConnectionStrings.config file on the development environment we can use the WSAT locally to manage users and roles in the production environment.

Comment: thanks for the reply ,, but what should my connection string looks like to be able to work with the WSAT locally for managing the production environment..